# Routing with parameters in jade from one page to another

Tags: node.js, express, pug

As i am new to nodejs and express, i would need some help here which could solve my problem. I have table(jade) on the page track.jade which contains information, with "ID" linking to another page. Successfully i can route to another page. But i need to pass the parameters from the table "track.jade" to another page within the table.

How can i achieve this? as i am not able find any article which could determine this issue.

```
    mixin session(AWB_NO, Product_Name, PCS, Weight, Gross_Weight, DOP, DOE)
tr
td.session(data-sort-value="#{session_name}")
.flex.sm
div
a.name(href="/track/dist.jade") #{AWB_NO}
div
td.min(data-label="Name") #{Product_Name}
td.min(data-label="file") #{PCS}
td.min(data-label="s_name") #{Weight}
td.min(data-label="r_name") #{Gross_Weight}
td.min(data-label="Date") #{DOP}
td.min(data-label="Date") #{DOE}
td.remove
a.btn-remove
img(src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/5102/remove.svg", alt="Remove Session")
span Remove 
.container
.event-registration.reset
.content.wide
.row-inset
table.table-default.table-striped.table-bordered.sortable
thead(data-header="true")
tr
th(data-sort-column="true") AWB NO
th(data-sort-column="true") Product Name
th(data-sort-column="true") PCS
th(data-sort-column="true") Weight
th(data-sort-column="true") Gross Weight
th(data-sort-column="true") Date of Packing
th(data-sort-column="true") Date of Expiry
// th(data-sort-column="true") DOR
th
tbody(data-body="true")
+session("16783","Tuna Super","10","12,6","13","03/28/2017","04/28/2017")
+session("17670936423","Fresh Sword Fish","1","12,8","13,6","03/28/2017","04/28/2017")
+session("178529","Fresh Fish","8","10","11","03/28/2017","04/28/2017")
+session("16254","Baramundi","5","11","12","03/28/2017","04/28/2017")
```

i had tried routing from one page to another page with the url localhost:3000/track/dist.jade

Comment: Some code would be needed to better understand your problem

Comment: @StephenS Thank you for the reply, please check the main answer i have edited with code. Here "a.name(href="/track/dist.jade") #{AWB_NO}" i am trying to route but it routes to next page. After how i can pass values to the next page from track.jade.

Comment: AFAIK you can't simply route to a jade file. You need to create routes with the express router and use those url's in your jade file. You can look at the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) for using template engines with express.

Comment: I have the dist.js in the route folder which is actually routing me to the next page. After routing the page i need to route along with values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the href value to the route set in the express router. The parameter can then be received in the dist route as a request param.

track.jade

```
a.name(href="/dist/" + AWB_NO ) #{AWB_NO}
```

dist.js

```
router.get('/dist/:awb', ensureLoggedIn, utils.checkAdmin, function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dist',{
        AWB_NO: req.params.awb
    })    
});
```

Comment: Thank you stephen, that helped me a lot ! but later i have noticed that the url capturing the id but why it is not navigating to dist.jade where i also need to pass this "awb_no" to this table.

Comment: You cannot navigate to the jade file, its simply a template. Once the template renders, it's html is created so it cannot be changed. You can route to a new page or use client side JavaScript to load something in the same page using AJAX calls

Comment: So after when template is rendered, is it not possible to load view on this page "localhost:3000/track/12345" or should i need to route from "/12345/test" to pass values from one page to another page. Like i have table in track.jade id "12345" respective to that i need to pass those "12345" values to dist.jade table. Something like this https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.15/docs/guide/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef.html

Comment: So i had tried using ajax something like this but nothing works.

client side:
 script.
            $.get( "/dest", function( data ) {
            name = data.name;
          });

server side
app.get("/dest", function(req, res){
  res.json({ name: "example" });
});

Comment: The SAPUI5 link that you shared, uses client side hash routes which uses some javascript trickery and is generally done with a framework(Angular, react, vue or something like SAPUI5). These are known as SPA's(Single page application) which let you navigate between content on the same page without page redirect. Jade however is server-side rendered and you can't load anything without a page redirect. So to load stuff after a page load you need client-side javascript and DOM manipulations.

Comment: Well i used to work with SAPUi5, so i thought it would be easier to explain here the output what i was thinking. Nevertheless since it's totally different, but still i have used the ajax call but i see nothing do you know where i am going wrong at the moment.

Comment: I too have worked on SAPUI5 for quite some time. In my opinion I think this question here is related to jade/pug routing in express, you could post a new question which focuses on your client-side routing problem.