# route with params 404 not found

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I would need some help as i am quit lost after this stage, i am trying to route with params but after that i am lost how to load page to this url localhost:3000/dist/16783 after when page route it says 404 not found. I would need some help how can i navigate to new page after this with id "16783" with values inside the table ex: tracking no "16783" or load view on the same page.

```
router.get('/dist/:awb', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dist', {
        AWB_NO: req.params.awb
    })
});
```

It is not rendering the page "dist", this question can related to this 
[Routing with parameters in jade from one page to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593575/routing-with-parameters-in-jade-from-one-page-to-another/56596643?noredirect=1#comment99775387_56596643)

EDIT:
Structure:

```
views:
   index.ejs
   track.ejs
   dist.ejs
routes:
   index.js
   track.js
   dist.js
app.js
package.json
```

app.js:

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var trackRouter = require('./routes/track');
var distRouter = require('./routes/dist');

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/track', trackRouter);
app.use('/dist',distRouter);
```

track.ejs

table column AWB NO link to dist page

```
 a.name(href="/dist/" + AWB_NO) #{AWB_NO}
            div
              td.min(data-label="Name") #{Product_Name}
              td.min(data-label="file") #{PCS}
              td.min(data-label="s_name") #{Weight}
              td.min(data-label="r_name") #{Gross_Weight}
              td.min(data-label="Date") #{DOP}
              td.min(data-label="Date") #{DOE}
```

So here is the actual problem, as when i have value inside this column "AWBNO" which link to "dist" page. Now when i click its passing params to url dist/16783, but nothing is loading

routes:

track.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
```

dist.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dist.ejs');
});

router.get('/:awb', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dist.ejs', {
        AWB_NO: req.params.awb
    })
});
```

New Update:

index.ejs

```
  <tr>
        <td class="id"><a href="/dist">1687952</a></td>
        <td>Tuna Fish</td>
        <td>DHL</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
```

index.js

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM orders', function (err, rows) {

        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err);
            res.render('index', { page_title: "index - Node.js", data: '' });
        } else {

            res.render('index', { page_title: "index - Node.js", data: rows });

        }


    });
});
```

dist.ejs

```
<li class="list-inline-item">AWB Nummber:<%= AWB_NO %></li> &nbsp;
```

dist.js

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM deliveries', function (err, rows) {

        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err);
            res.render('dist', { page_title: "dist - Node.js", data: '' });
        } else {

            res.render('dist', { page_title: "dist - Node.js", data: rows });

        }


    });
    router.get('/dist/:awb', function (req, res) {
        res.render('dist', {
            AWB_NO: req.params.awb
        })
    });
});
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: E:\Dev\admeghbalim\YinSeafood\YinSeafood\expressfirst\views\dist.ejs:20
    18|             <h3>Distributor information</h3><br>&nbsp;
    19|             <ul class="list-inline">
 >> 20|                 <li class="list-inline-item">AWB Nummber:<%= AWB_NO %></li> &nbsp;
    21|                 <li class="list-inline-item">Country:</li>&nbsp;
    22|                 <li class="list-inline-item">Date:</li>&nbsp;
    23|                 <li class="list-inline-item">Sender:</li>&nbsp;

AWB_NO is not defined
```

Comment: You have some errors in your new dist.js file. The second router.get is defined in the first router.get callback. The closing brackets should be placed before the next route, instead of placing it at the end. Also the route should be `'/:awb'` instead of `'/dist/:awb'`

Comment: The Error what is see in the referenceError attached in the main question. Even though after trying to pass the object.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere here:

    <th class="text-center">AWB NO</th>
        <th class="text-center">Date</th>
        <th class="text-center">Supplier</th>
        <th class="text-center">Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
     <td class="id"><a href="/dist/" + AWB_NO>1687952</a></td>

Answer (score 0):

I think the route here might be relative to the route you may have set in the express base configuration.

If you have have something like this in your app.js

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
app.use('/dist', require("./routes/dist"));
//Set the view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

And your dist.js has a route

```
router.get('/dist/:awb', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dist', {
        AWB_NO: req.params.awb
    })
});
```

Your route will effectively be

> localhost:3000/dist/dist/16783

as the path is relative to your root path in `app.use`. In this case your path should be

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dist');
});

router.get('/:awb', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dist', {
        AWB_NO: req.params.awb
    })
});
```

Comment: So when i click to number or id, will i be directed to the another page or same page. Right now as you have suggested the url works fine but on the same i need to see the dist.ejs or jade view. Will the /:awb do that ? as i try to render the 'dist' is not happening.

Comment: You'll be redirected to a new page. To view it on the same page you'll need some client-side javascript.

Comment: As you said i was redirected to the url dist/16783, but i am trying to load the page with view by render "dist" why it says 404 not found. 
router.get('/:awb', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dist', { title:'Express'
    })
});

Comment: I am afraid, it's difficult to understand the problem without having a look at the application structure and the file where you create the `express()` instance

Comment: I have edited the section, please check the original question.

Comment: I have updated the answer a bit, but do you get a 404 error on the page or does it not render correctly. If the rendering is a problem, check the console for errors or the  dist.ejs for issues.

Comment: I get 404 error on the page when i get the url is /dist/16783 but if i just load the page localhost:3000/dist i see the page. But if i render it with :id "dist" page i get the error

Comment: Based on the code you have shared, it works for me. I believe it has something to do with some of the other parts of your code. If you have console errors those might help to narrow it down.

Comment: Alright ! then i will test back and let you know asap.

Comment: Alright ! then i will test back and let you know asap. And do you see the url dist/16783 and on the same page you are loading the "dist" view ?

Comment: Yeah, it's a simple link so it will open on the same tab

Comment: So after passing the id to url i need to know if possible. how to pass the same id to the table row for ex: i am passing the parameter "id" to the url instead i need to pass the same id to the dist view table under "Product number"

Comment: You can use the object key `AWB_NO` provided in the render function as a variable to the dist.ejs file as `<td><%= AWB_NO %></td>`

Comment: Is it possible to render the function to li as i am trying to render the AWB_NO to the list.
  <li class="list-inline-item"><%= AWB_NO %>AWB Nummber:</li> &nbsp;
                <li class="list-inline-item">Country:</li>&nbsp;
                <li class="list-inline-item">Date:</li>&nbsp;
                <li class="list-inline-item">Sender:</li>&nbsp;

Comment: Yeah you can use it in the li tag `<li class="list-inline-item">AWB Number:<%= AWB_NO %></li>`

Comment: In the same conecpt i am trying to render like this <td class="id"><a href="/dist" + AWB_NO>1784598</a></td> but nothing's working.

Comment: `<td class="id"><a href="/dist/<%=AWB_NO%>">1784598</a></td>`

Comment: I am sorry for looping the problem. But not it says "AWB_NO is not defined", please see my main question. I think if i get this 30% of my job is done.

Comment: You have to pass the object with AWB_NO to the render function in the route `res.render('dist', { AWB_NO: req.params.awb })`. If you call render without it, AWB_NO will be undefined.

Comment: Yes i tried passing the object to the index.ejs table   <td class="id"><a href="/dist" + AWB_No>1687952</a></td> but i see the same error when i click on the table it will route to dist page with the above error.

Comment: I cant seem to find anything wrong with it. Case-sensitivity maybe ? `AWB_No` and `AWB_NO` are different.

Comment: even i tried with that its same error, i have updated the main question with New Update. May you can tell me on that where i am going wrong and i have passed the object in index.ejs